# Repositioning a listpage in ax 2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I inserted a button(action menu item) on a list page.  on selecting a record and clicking on button it copies and creates a new record. After creation the list page still shows the selected record. I want to point to the newly created record. I tried

formdatasource.reload();

formdatasource.refresh();

formdatasource.findrecord(salestable);

formdatasource.research(true);

But it either positions to selected record or to last page, but not to newly created record.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`findRecord` should do the trick, but you must first `research` to make the new record available for selection. See also [Refresh DataSource and retain position](http://devexpp.blogspot.de/2012/02/refresh-datasource-and-retain-position.html) 
.